# Using forward slash as path separator in Unix and Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unix, path

I'm doing some file management in a Python 2.7 application in both Unix and Windows. This results in having to do alot of path concatenation with [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Now I want the `os.path` functions (e.g. `join`, `relpath`) to return a string with forward slashes as path separators on both Unix and Windows. Is there some global setting I can use or is it necessary to use another function to convert the result of the functions?

Comment: May I ask why you want this?

Comment: @martineau I'm writing and comparng many of the paths to XML-files and these all need to be done with forward slashes

Comment: I'm populating one big XML file (and some other file types along with some database tables) which is later read by other applications which expects the paths to be in the Unix format

Comment: but it will be of two different file system structures. Posix has no sense of `C:\>`

Comment: Perhaps you could create your own `join()` function by looking at the source code definitions of it in your `Python/Lib/ntpath.py` and `Python/Lib/posixpath.py` source files and create one that does what you want.

Comment: @cwallenpoole That's a good point, preferably it would replace `C:` with simply `/`. Maybe I should rethink this though...

Comment: I thought maybe you could assign to `os.sep`, but apparently this doesn't change how `os.path.join` works.

Comment: After investigating my options I've reached the conclusion that I will still have to use `/`, even in Windows. The paths in the XML files are always relative to a directory that is never at the root. Some of the XML files also need to follow some standards that require the use of `/` in file paths. This means that drive letters are not a problem.